# PHP : Is calculating with strings reliable

Tags: php

In PHP I make a simple calculation, but with strings

```
$num_1 = '200.50'; (string)
$num_2 = '100.50'; (string)

echo $num_1 - $num_2
```

The result is as expected `100.00`

What I wonder about is the fact that I did not cast the values to float and still got the correct result.
And my question is if this kind of (string) calculation is reliable ?

Comment: It's called "PHP type juggling". Your two strings are used in a numeric context, so they get converted to floats.

Comment: Try this and see ---> echo gettype($num_1 - $num_2); // double

Comment: PHP autocasts variables. When you try to do math on a string var, it's converted to a integer. Likewise if you try string operations on an int, it becomes a string $a =2;  $b = $a .' I am a string now';
echo $b; // "2 I am a string now"

Comment: arbitrarily calculating with strings should be reliable - if your data is thoroughly checked. but if you check it in the first place, why don't you use actual numeric data types instead? that's far more reliable, performante, intuitive, whereas using strings where numbers should be used is good sign that something is fundamentally flawed with your code. you could do it - but you definitely never should.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann - You're right. But in my case the numbers are coming from a DB and are stored as varchars instead of floats. I want avoid hassles having different results with floating point calculation from different kind of server CPU's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reliable if you use numbers in your string. If you use alphabet characters, special characters, or other things you wouldn't expect in basic maths, you may get unexpected results.

To learn more about what behavior you can expect and how to prevent issues, see the PHP docs for type juggling.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Hi guys - quick answers - super. Rizier123 was first but Goose gave the most complete answer. So I accept his answer - okay ?

Comment: Goose - nice website ;-)